# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=11

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Salary.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1/3, 
random_state=0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
simplelinearRegresson = LinearRegression()
simplelinearRegresson.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = simplelinearRegresson.predict(X_test)
```

Below line has error:

```
 y_predict_val = simplelinearRegresson.predict(11)
```

Comment: Do you need any additional help on this one?

Comment: Please also put your required problem in body of your question, to get answer from community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your scalar to a 2D array with shape `(number of samples, number of features)`.

```
y_predict_val = simplelinearRegresson.predict([[11]])
```

This is what the `predict` method expects. See [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict) for more info.

Comment: y_predict_val = LinearRegression.predict([[11]])
TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X

Comment: `simplelinearRegresson.predict([[11]])`, not `LinearRegression.predict([[11]])`